# Why is the LinkedIn API showing different permissions for an iPhone versus web browser?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an existing app registered with LinkedIn. When authenticating through a web browser, I get the expected permissions:

[Permissions box in Chrome web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etsl1.png)

However, when authenticating through an iPhone for *the same* existing app, the permissions box is missing "Use your name, headline, and photo" and "Use your basic profile including your name, photo, headline, and current positions":

[Permissions box on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vsid.png)

I am aware LinkedIn is once again limiting access to API developers but the deadline is March 1st, 2019 and it appears some rules enforcement in the API is treating my existing app as a newly registered app.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. While my app's default permissions included `r_basicprofile`, I was passing a `scope` parameter which did *not* include `r_basicprofile` or any other profile scope.